# Why displays only last element of array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am reading txt file

```
antonio;alex antonio;antonio@mail.com

griez;Antuan Griezmann;griez@google.com

trump;Donald Trump;trump@google.com
```

with that method

```
 public  String getInput(String fileName) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName), "UTF-8");
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine()).append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            scanner.close();
            return sb.toString().trim();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

then i try to split the input data with regex "\n"

```
public String [] arrSplit(String input){
        return input.split("\n");
    }
```

and i get only last element in console

[image: my output]

My main method where i am running

```
  String text = util.getInput("text.txt");

        Ts test = new Ts();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.arrSplit(text)));
```

[image: the string are the same but output different]

Comment: Is the file content the same as you have posted ?

Comment: @dreamcrash added new image which shows output of file and simple string with the same output

Comment: But you get an array [Login;Name;Email, , antonio;alex antonio;antonio@mail.com, , griez;Antuan Griezmann;griez@google.com, , trump;Donald Trump;trump@google.com]

Comment: @dreamcrash i get correct array with simple string, not with file

Comment: I just test your code and I got this:

[Login;Name;Email, , antonio;alex antonio;antonio@mail.com, , griez;Antuan Griezmann;griez@google.com, , trump;Donald Trump;trump@google.com]

Comment: You can see it(2nd array which got from file) displays only ", trump;Donald Trump;trump@google.com]".

Comment: It does not happen to me. Are you sure there not more in your main method?

Comment: @dreamcrash did you create a file?

Comment: Yes. exactly like yours

Comment: @dreamcrash no way to me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225567/discussion-between-ross-and-dreamcrash).

Comment: Okey, does not matter you have it solve now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the correct regex to split you should use `split("\\n")` or even better `split("\\r?\\n");` which will work with different line separators.